# Changing Imagebackground for UIbutton ios losing border

Tags: ios

Why does the border of the first button disapper when i set the selection to NO?  Below are the two actions for foreach of the buttons.

```
- (IBAction)onehourbtn:(id)sender
{
    [btnonehour setSelected:YES];
    [btntwohour setSelected:NO];
    [btnthreehour setSelected:NO];
}
```

and

```
(IBAction)twohourbtn:(id)sender
{
    [btnonehour setSelected:NO];
    [btntwohour setSelected:YES];
    [btnthreehour setSelected:NO];
}
```

[image: Clicked on button moved away]

[image: Clicked on the other button and the border is removed from the first]

Comment: are you creating the buttons via InterfaceBuilder? or programmatically? If the latter, post the code.

Comment: Hello, I am creating the buttons in IB.  The only thing i am setting programmatically is the selection.  In IB, for selected i set an image for background.

Comment: does the selected image have a border?

Comment: LOL! Just set up a test project, it does it for me also. Looks like you'll have to provide a button image for default also.

Comment: I don't believe.  I dont see where to change border in IB.  Why would that affect the button when its not in the selected state?

Comment: :) Thanks I didnt think i was going crazy

Comment: I don't think it should but it definitely does. The border isn't the matter here, I think you'll need to provide a white image with the border for the unselected. BTW, it isn't removing the border, it's removing the image altogether, change your view BG to grey to see what I mean.